# Find recurrencies in pairs distributed in 2 columns of a data.frame

Tags: r, combinatorics, word-frequency

Let's say that there is a need to find out frequencies for each pair:

Eg. `Mark` -`Maria` appears three times and the rest one time

```
Name1   Name2
Mark    Maria
John    Xesca
Steve   Rose
Mark    Maria
John    John
Mark    Maria
John    Xesca
```

Which is the best way to perform this? Take into account that those are frequencies for both elements. I think this is more complex than the expected... Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

If you need to take account of the order of name1 and name2 :

```
subset(as.data.frame(table(df)), Freq > 0)

#    Name1 Name2 Freq
# 1   John  John    1
# 5   Mark Maria    3
# 9  Steve  Rose    1
# 10  John Xesca    2
```

Answer (score 2):

We loop through the rows of the dataset, `sort` and `paste` it together, then get the frequency with `table`

```
table(apply(df1, 1, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse='-')))
#    John-John John-Xesca Maria-Mark Rose-Steve 
#        1          2          3          1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name1 = c("Mark", "John", "Steve", "Mark", "John", 
 "Mark", "John"), Name2 = c("Maria", "Xesca", "Rose", "Maria", 
 "John", "Maria", "Xesca")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -7L))
```

Comment: But, i've tried with another data and I want to differentiate, for instance, between John-Xesca and Xesca-John (it is not the same combination). I really like your method.

Comment: @fina  I thought both of them belog to same combination.  Otherwise just do `table(df1)`

Comment: Super, that's what I was looking for. A matrix is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't even need to paste, just group:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(Name1, Name2) %>% 
  count()
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# # Groups:   Name1, Name2 [4]
# Name1 Name2     n
# <fct> <fct> <int>
# 1 John  John      1
# 2 John  Xesca     2
# 3 Mark  Maria     3
# 4 Steve Rose      1
```

---

You can `paste0` together the columns then `count` with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  mutate(pasted = paste0(Name1,Name2)) %>% 
  group_by(pasted) %>% 
  count()
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
# # Groups:   pasted [4]
# pasted        n
# <chr>     <int>
# 1 JohnJohn      1
# 2 JohnXesca     2
# 3 MarkMaria     3
# 4 SteveRose     1
```

Note that `JohnXesca` will be treated as different from `XescaJohn`.

Data:

```
tt <- "Name1   Name2
Mark    Maria
John    Xesca
Steve   Rose
Mark    Maria
John    John
Mark    Maria
John    Xesca"

dat <- read.table(text=tt, header = T)
```